# Sorting 2D List in Python

Tags: python

Using .sort() in Python, how do I sort a 2D list e.g.:

```
myVar = [['blueberries','fruit','5.20'],['bean sprouts','vegetable','9.25'],['tulip','flower','8.93']]
#added comma
```

by item e.g.,:

```
myVar = [['bean sprouts','vegetable','9.25'],['blueberries','fruit','5.20'],['tulip','flower','8.93']]
```

by price e.g.,:

```
myVar = [['blueberries','fruit','5.20'],['tulip','flower','8.93'],['bean sprouts','vegetable','9.25']]
```

where "blueberries, bean sprouts and tulips" are items, "fruit, vegetable and flower" are categories and the floats are prices.

Comment: Any elements in lists have to be separated by commas. Please don't use ```list``` as a variable as it is an inbuilt function

Comment: Take a look at the 'sorted' builtin function and, in particular, the [optional] 'key' named parameter

Answer (score 1):

Consider using something like this:-

```
myList = [['blueberries', 'fruit', 5.20], [
    'bean sprouts', 'vegetable', 9.25], ['tulip', 'flower', 8.93]]

for i in range(3):
    print(sorted(myList, key=lambda x: x[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to put commas between the elements of a list

```
myVar = [['blueberries','fruit','5.20'],
         ['bean sprouts','vegetable','9.25'],
         ['tulip','flower','8.93']]
```

Now you could use the `sorted` builtin as Andy Knight suggested in the comments and specify a `key` function to use for comparing items.

Sort list by price and get a copy of the sorted list

```
sorted(myVar, key=lambda x: float(x[2]))
```

Sort list by item name

```
sorted(myVar, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda`

For example,

Sorting by item:

```
list.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
```

Sorting by price:

```
list.sort(key = lambda x : x[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `sorted` function:

```
def Sort(sub_li):
    return(sorted(sub_li, key = lambda x: x[2]))    

sub_li =[['blueberries','fruit','5.20'],['bean sprouts','vegetable','9.25'],['tulip','flower','8.93']]
print(Sort(sub_li))
```